# How to display categories in a selectbox?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, advanced-search

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 and i want to display categories in a select-box and sub-categories in an other select-box.

I want to have two drop-down the first are for the categories and the second for the subcategories and When i select the categories in the first drop-down the second drop-down must changed and display the subcategories of the category selected in the first drop-down

How i do that? thanks

Comment: Where do you want to do it? Layered navigation, top navigation, custom page?

Comment: Advanced Search

Comment: Ok. In this case I don't understand your idea about displaying categories and subcategories at the same time. Which you want first dropdown to display top categories and once something is selected there the 2nd dropdown is automatically populated with subcategories of the category selected in 1st dropdown?

Comment: I want to have two dropdown the first are for the categories and the second for the subcategories and When i select the categories in the first dropdown the second dropdown must changed and display the subcategories of the category selected in the first dropdown.

Comment: It will make sense to update the question with all this info.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this may resolve the issue::

First, we'll create a directory structure for this module. Our directory structure should look as follows:

- app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/Block
- app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/controllers
- app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc
- app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/Helper
- app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/Model
- app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/sql

Then create a configuration file for the module `(at pathapp/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc/config.xml):`

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then create a file to activate the module `(at path app/etc/modules/Magentotutorial_Helloworld.xml)`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Finally, we ensure the module is active:

1. Clear your Magento cache.
2. In the Magento Admin, go to System->Configuration->Advanced.
3. Expand "Disable Modules Output" (if it isn't already).
4. Ensure that Magentotutorial_Helloworld shows up.

Next, we're going to configure a route. A route will turn a URL into an Action Controller and a method. Unlike other convention based PHP MVC systems, with Magento you need to explicitly define a route in the global Magento config.
In your `config.xml file`, add the following section:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            < Magentotutorial_Helloworld >
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </ Magentotutorial_Helloworld >
        </modules>   
<frontend>
<routers>
  <helloworld>
    <use>standard</use>
    <args>
      <module> Magentotutorial_Helloworld </module>
      <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
    </args>
  </helloworld>
</routers>
<layout>
  <updates>
    <helloworld>
      <file>helloworld.xml</file
    </helloworld>
  </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

You should either create a controller,for example:

Step1:`Magentotutorial/Helloworld/controllers/Ajaxcontroller.php` or create a new action in the existing controller
Step2:To create an action in your controller,such as `indexAction()`,you would add this code.

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Step3:Then add to `helloworld.xml(example:app/design/frontend/default/…/layout/helloworld.xml)` next code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
        <helloworld_ajax_index>
            <block type="core/template" name="root" output="toHtml" template="helloworld/index.phtml" />
        </helloworld_ajax_index>
    </layout>
```

Step4:Then create your index.phtml file to show the subcategories by category id request by ajax call(`example:app/design/frontend/default/…/template/helloworld/index.phtml`)

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>  
    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_POST['id']) ?>
        <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>                
                     <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>               
                            <option><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></option>
      <?php endforeach ?>   
                <?php endif ?>
```

Step5:Create a select box to show the categories for ex:

```
<select class="select" id="option" value="option" name="option">
<option value="*">Full Stock List</option>
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $_category->getId() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></option>      
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

Step6:After that make a ajax call to the file which is index.phtml (`template/ helloworld/index.phtml`)it will post the id of category into index.phtml and a another selectbox which have id option create where you want for ex.

Step:7After that post category id to the the file to get the results in the selct box

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
{   
    jQuery("#option").change(function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).val();

jQuery.ajax({
url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('helloworld/ajax/index') ?>",
type: "POST",
data: {id:id},
success: function(data) {
jQuery(".state").html(data); 
}
});
return false;});})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my code below this should get you started
**PLEASE NOTE THIS IS CE 1.6.2**

```
 <form>
    <select class="select" id="option" value="option" name="option">
    <option value="*">Full Stock List</option>
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
    <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $_category->getId() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></option>      
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </select>
    <input id="SubmitButton" class="button-link" type="button" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: That diplay only me the form and not the data categories

Comment: This is in the advanced search yes? try this code within the advanced search Phtml file. All this will do will show you the categories, it will not filter into search results.